# How to search the file with recent timestamp using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following kind of n number of files in a folder.

```
 log_20140114-10-43-20_5750.txt
 log_20140114-10-43-23_5750.txt
 log_20140114-10-43-25_5750.txt
```

here the only variation in all the above files are timestamp only. but I need the files which is having the latest timestamp. I mean i need the "log_20140114-10-43-25_5750.txt" file only.

I am very new to python.Please help me

Comment: By 'timestamp' do you mean the one in the file name or the actual OS timestamp?

Comment: @abarnert if the "5750" in the file names tell me how to make it as a list??

Comment: @user3116273: I don't understand what you mean. Are you asking how to get a list of all files in the current directory with `5750` anywhere in their name? That's just `glob.glob('*5750*'))`. It works the same as a Unix shell (and not that different from a Windows shell). See [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) in the docs. You can also use [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) if you already have the filenames and just want to filter them, or `re` if you need a more powerful pattern (as in Jubjub Bandersnatch's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
import re

r = re.compile(r'log_\d{8}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{4}\.txt$')

latest_file = \
    max(filter(r.search,os.listdir('/path/to/logs')))

print(latest_file)
```

(Edited to include filtering the list of files and take @abarnert's efficiency advice.)

Comment: The only problem is if there are *other* files in the directory they might always be max.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Yeah, in that case you'd probably want to `max` on `glob` rather than `listdir` (to filter out the other files). (Fortunately, at least you can count on `._.DS_Store` and other such unexpected hidden files never being max.)

Comment: If you really want to use `re` instead, you might as well at least `re.compile` it. (And then you can just pass `r.search` as the filter predicate and get rid of the lambda, and the whole expression is only 41 characters instead of taking multiple lines and still scrolling horizontally.)

Comment: @abarnert Thanks. I prefer re to glob in this case just because you have more control, not because it's faster. `glob()` is still probably the most practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

If file name already have timestamp in it you can sort names and use last name from list:

```
lst = os.listdir('.')
lst.sort()
print(lst[-1])
```

Comment: Sorting just to get the highest one is both overly complex and wasteful. What's wrong with `max`?

Comment: You are right, for this example `max()` is better. `sort()` can be useful if he had to check something in those logs and it had to be done in particular order.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

filelist = glob.glob('./log*.txt')
filelist.sort()
print filelist[-1]
```

Comment: Sorting just to get the highest one is both overly complex and wasteful. What's wrong with `max`?

Comment: All that is wrong with `max` is that I didn't think of it first!  Of course sometimes you also need other ordinals later then it does come in useful.

Comment: I can't imagine he'll need the 8th, 17th, and 33rd newest. He might conceivably need the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd (for which `nlargest` is still much better than `sort`), but he didn't ask for even that.